# can't assign an id value to an html input tag

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have to do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/3yP84/1/

The task is simple: assign an id to an input tag in html and get the value through javascript. I have done the SAME thing on my application (the code is very large, so i will not post it here!), but it does not work.
I have something like:

```
<div id="old_pw_sp" class="col-xs-7">
<input type="password" id="current_password"/>
</div>
```

and the same js of the fiddle (whit right names of the div):

```
var crr_pw = document.getElementById("current_password").value;
```

but I keep gettin the error:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

If i analyze the input tag with firefox analyzer I get this:

```
<div id="old_pw_sp" class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="password">
</div>
```

The id is not there, but I cannot figure out why. Can someone please help me?

EDIT!
I'm stupid: I was editing a file and I was loading on the application another. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: will you search for string "current_password" in file and see if it matches in both the places?

Comment: I think you have duplicate id

Comment: Refresh bypassing cache (shift+F5 on Windows), or close browser and reload page, or clear cache completely and reload. You might also make another change on the page and then view it to see if the change is actually loaded.

Comment: Check for some other js code manipulating your html. Start from changing your input type="password" to type="text" (just for the sake of testing)

Comment: updated your fiddle, try it http://jsfiddle.net/nagarkoti/3yP84/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use as below

```
 <div id="old_pw_sp" class="col-xs-7">
 <input type="password" id="current_password"/>
</div>
<div id="click_here" onclick="showPassword();">Click</div>

function showPassword(){
 alert(document.getElementById("current_password").value);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qdzz6/)